Some troubles about Github Action workflows and branch protection
Problem
I have a format workflow, which will run some format code, such as gofmt, and then push to the source branch of the pull request. For example:
name: Format

on:
  pull_request_target:
    branches:
      - master

permissions:
  contents: write

jobs:
  format:
    runs-on: 'ubuntu-latest'

    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
        with:
          ref: ${{ github.head_ref }}

      - name: Set up Go
        uses: actions/setup-go@v5
        with:
          go-version: '1.22'

      - name: gofmt
        run: |
          if [ "$(gofmt -s -l -w . | wc -l)" -gt 0 ]; then
          git config --local user.name 'github-actions[bot]'
          git config --local user.email '41898282+github-actions[bot]@users.noreply.github.com'
          git add --all
          git commit -m "gofmt"
          git push
          fi

Okey, it works well.
Now I have another workflow named build, witch will run go test and go build.
Then I set my branch protected strategy: build workflow must pass before merging the pull request.
When a pull request is opened, gofmt workflow runs and push a new commit to the pull request source branch. But this new commit by gofmt workflow cannot trigger build workflow automatically because of Github Action's security policy. So I can't merge the pull request for a reason that build workflow doesn't pass.
Expecting

Pull request will be formatted automatically.
The branch protected strategy works. (build workflow must pass before merge the pull request.)
I can merge the pull request.

or:

fmt workflow can work on push event on master branch and bypass the branch protected strategy.

Either of the two solutions above can solve my problem.

Edited on 2024-4-10
Github Docs:
https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/automatic-token-authentication#using-the-github_token-in-a-workflow

When you use the repository's GITHUB_TOKEN to perform tasks, events
triggered by the GITHUB_TOKEN, with the exception of
workflow_dispatch and repository_dispatch, will not create a new
workflow run. This prevents you from accidentally creating recursive
workflow runs. For example, if a workflow run pushes code using the
repository's GITHUB_TOKEN, a new workflow will not run even when the
repository contains a workflow configured to run when push events
occur.
Commits pushed by a GitHub Actions workflow that uses the
GITHUB_TOKEN do not trigger a GitHub Pages build.

Then I tried to use PAT instead of GITHUB_TOKEN, like this:
      - name: gofmt
        env:
          PAT: ${{ secrets.GH_PAT }}
        run: |
          if [ "$(gofmt -s -l -w . | wc -l)" -gt 0 ]; then
          git config --local user.name 'github-actions[bot]'
          git config --local user.email '41898282+github-actions[bot]@users.noreply.github.com'
          git add --all
          git commit -m "gofmt"
          git push
          fi

It could not trigger the build workflow, either. I am not sure whether I use PAT here properly.

What is the specific Github Action's security policy which is preventing you from triggering the second workflow? Is it the one using the Github Token to trigger workflow in sequence?

If you push some commits, on: push workflows will be triggered.
But if Github Actions push some commits, on: push workflows won't be triggered.
I guess Github is trying to prevent recursive calls.
The same to on: pull_request workflows.

PAT is needed in both actions/checkout and push jobs, like this:
name: GoFmt

on:
  pull_request:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:

  gofmt:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4
        with:
          ref: ${{ github.head_ref }}
          token: ${{ secrets.GH_PAT }}

      - name: Set up Go
        uses: actions/setup-go@v5
        with:
          go-version: '1.22'

      - name: gofmt
        run: |
          if [ "$(gofmt -s -l -w . | wc -l)" -gt 0 ]; then
          git config --local user.name 'github-actions[bot]'
          git config --local user.email '41898282+github-actions[bot]@users.noreply.github.com'
          git add --all
          git commit -m "gofmt"
          fi

      - name: Push changes
        uses: ad-m/github-push-action@master
        with:
          branch: ${{ github.head_ref }}
          github_token: ${{ secrets.GH_PAT }}

Now it works. When this format workflow pushes commits, the build workflow will be triggered.
